# tensorflow evaluate with confusion matrix

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-learn, tensorflow

In the [tensorflow CNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks), it computes the accuracy, but I want to leverage from that to the confusion matrix.

Immediately, three different approaches hit on my mind:

1. I tried to directly compute the prediction result instead of top_k_op in tensorflow, then I could utilize sklearn. But I failed, because the it used multiple threads to compute([line 88](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py));
2. I tried to load the trained Variables and give new placeholder to cifar10.inference, but failed again, because it defined batch_image as input([line 225](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py));
3. The last approach is to defined a new operation to replace the [line 128](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py)

   ```
   top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
   ```

   but I could not find a proper operations could do that.

This has afflicted me for several days. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize sklearn's confusion_matrix only after running 'inference' on all the dataset. 
Meaning, if you are modifying `eval_only` function, you should just accumulate all the scores into some thread-safe container (list). And then after all threads are stopped (line 113) you can run single confusion matrix computation.

Additionally, if you want to do it in the graph, TensorFlow recently got `confusion_matrix` [op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/confusion_matrix_ops.py) you can try using. That said, it only works on the batch so you will need to increase your batch to get any kind of resolution or write a custom aggregator.

Comment: Your first solution works well but not quite perfectly: when the number of examples is not multipliers of the number of batch, the number of examples to be evaluated is bigger than that of actual. Do you have an idea how to fix that problem? Thanks in advance.